# Amazon Cloud as a Server with alot of RAM

Tags: memory, database, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, gis

I need a server with very big size of RAM, so around a ~1TB, for a GIS DB, that would be not written to hard disk, because the data is irrelevant after a seconds. So i do not need a lot of disk space, i wish to hold all data in memory. So i need powerful CPU and very big RAM space. The write data would be 1% of INSERT'S and 99% of UPDATE's. Write/Read ratio would be 20/1. I have a choose, rent a dedicated server or rent a Amazon service. The problem is, that I don't understand, how to calculate the price of Amazon services. Traffic ~100TB/month.

Does not exists any calculator script for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I need 1TB RAM on a server

Comment: Split your data into regions with overlaps and serve each region from a different smaller sever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use the [Amazon Web Services Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) that AWS provides. You may not even need a EC2 instance, you may be better off getting a [RDS instance](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), you can use that instead of a EC2 instance for the database and use a lighter ec2 instance as the front end.

They do not offer a 1TB RDS or EC2 instance, the biggest RDS and EC2 instances only have 68 GB of ram (the "High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large" instance) are you sure you really need that much ram? You may be better off using the Provisioned IOPS feature to ensure that access to the disk drive is very fast. Your standard desktop SSD is going to have around 3,000-15,000 IOPS, you can get around 30,000 IOPS using provisioned IOPS using RDS.

Comment: Thank you for the link. In choose between SDD and RAM, SSD can try to hold on the same level if it is anything specific hardware on PCIe, but never the commonly hardware in mainstream DC. Anyway, SSD has low life capacity, yes I know, they are now much better, but if I make so much data change on it, the best of it will be fail out in 2-4 weeks.

Comment: Where did you get those numbers from, or did you just hear rumors? Modern SLC enterprise grade SSD's have lifespans in years even if you are pushing max IO 24/7. [There are big differences between consumer grade and enterprise grade SSDs](http://serverfault.com/questions/263694/why-is-enterprise-storage-so-expensive/263695#263695).

Comment: I have calculated the setup with best performance (High-MEM Cluster Eight Extra Large) that it is given by amazon. It would be cost the same, that i would be pay for a dedicated server with 1,5TB RAM, 4xE5-4620,~150TB traffic. After reading so much good things about Amazon cloud I am so sad now about it.

Comment: Then it is a question how much IOPS they have. I can not understand, what you wanna say with the link, have read the full answer, but not understand what do is have the same with my situation.